# 0-23 hour military clock to standard time (hh:mm)

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, time

How would I go about this process? Let's say that someone types in "3:5", and I should be able to get the output "3:05 AM". Or if someone types in "00:00", I should get "12:00 AM". I realize the plethora of ways to go about this if the time format was simply input as "hhmm", but the input can range from "h:m", "hh:m", "hh:m", and "hh:mm". So it's very situational.

```
def timeConvert():
    miliTime = int(input("Enter a time in hh:mm (military) format: "))
    miliTime.split(":")
    if len(miliTime) == 3:
        hours = miliTime[0]
        minutes = miliTime[2]
        if hours < 0:
            print("Hours can't be less than 0.")
    elif len(miliTime) == 4:
        if miliTime[0:2] >= 10:
            hours = militime[0:2]
            minutes = militime[3]
            if minutes < 0:
                print("Minutes can't be less than 0.")
            if minutes < 10:
                minutes = 0 + minutes
        else:
            hours = miliTime[0]
            minutes = militime[2:]
            if minutes >= 60:
                print("Too big of a number for minutes.")
    else:
        hours = miliTime[0:2]
        minutes = miliTime[3:]
    setting = AM
    if hours > 12:
        setting = PM
        hours -= 12
    print(hours + ":" + minutes + setting)

timeConvert()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the input by `:`, and use formatted output in the end:

```
def timeConvert():
    miliTime = input("Enter a time in hh:mm (military) format: ")
    hours, minutes = miliTime.split(":")
    hours, minutes = int(hours), int(minutes)
    setting = "AM"
    if hours > 12:
        setting = "PM"
        hours -= 12
    print(("%02d:%02d" + setting) % (hours, minutes))
```

Comment: Note for OP: when the input is `"00:00"`, the output is `"00:00 AM"` (not `"12:00 AM"`), this is correct, isn't it? If it's not, modifying it is relatively easy.

Answer (score 26):

Use the datetime module's `strptime()` to read the string as a datetime object and then convert it back to string using `strftime()` , example -

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('3:5','%H:%M').strftime('%I:%M %p')
'03:05 AM'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('18:30','%H:%M').strftime('%I:%M %p')
'06:30 PM'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00','%H:%M').strftime('%I:%M %p')
'12:00 AM'
```

The formats explained -

> %H - Hour (24-hour fomrat)
>
> %M - Minute
>
> %I - Hour (12-hour format)
>
> %p - AM or PM

---

Function would look like -

```
def timeConvert():
    import datetime
    ds = input("Enter a time in hh:mm (military) format: ")
    newds = datetime.datetime.strptime(ds, ,'%H:%M').strftime('%I:%M %p')
    print(newds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply combine the 2 columns in a string function.  I worked on the assumption you're using the 24 hour clock or military time down to the minute (the 100?)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

for i in df.columns:

    df[i] = df[i].apply(str)


df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(4)))


df
Out[11]: 
      ccy      date time    open    high     low   close            datetime
0  EURUSD  20190211  100  1.1318  1.1319  1.1317  1.1319 2019-02-11 01:00:00
1  EURUSD  20190211  200   1.132  1.1322  1.1319  1.1319 2019-02-11 02:00:00
2  EURUSD  20190211  300  1.1318  1.1319  1.1318  1.1319 2019-02-11 03:00:00
3  EURUSD  20190211  400  1.1319  1.1319  1.1318  1.1318 2019-02-11 04:00:00
4  EURUSD  20190211  500  1.1318  1.1318  1.1318  1.1318 2019-02-11 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
military_time = input("Enter a military time (0000 to 2359): ")
hours = int(military_time[0:2])
minutes = int(military_time[2:4])
if hours >= 12:
    meridian = "pm"
    hours %= 12
else:
    meridian = "am"
if hours == 0:
    hours = 12
print("The regular time is {0}:{1} {2}.".format(hours, minutes, meridian))
```

Comment: After accepting the input convert it into integers and slice the time [0:2] to get the hours and [2:4] to get the minutes, after you check if hours >= 12 then you can take the % of hours by 12 and take the remainder as your regular time or if hours == 0 then you just equate the hours to 12