# how to change datetime into normal format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCBjD.png)
But every time when I want to change the date format or use the date it shows hour should be in 0...23
How to change all the data into normal format?

Comment: what do you mean by normal format?

Comment: The midnight hour should shown as 00:00 instead of 24:00.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse this twice:

```
In [11]: dates = ['2015/01/04 23:59', '2015/01/04 24:00', '2015/01/05 00:01', '2015/01/05 00:02', '2015/01/05 00:03', '2015/01/05 00:04', '2015/01/05 00:05']
```

First i the usual way (you don't *have* to pass the format argument here).

```
In [12]: dates1 = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dates, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", errors='coerce'))

In [13]: dates1
Out[13]:
0   2015-01-04 23:59:00
1                   NaT
2   2015-01-05 00:01:00
3   2015-01-05 00:02:00
4   2015-01-05 00:03:00
5   2015-01-05 00:04:00
6   2015-01-05 00:05:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The second time only parse if the hour is 24 (and add day to the result):

```
In [14]: dates2 = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dates, format="%Y/%m/%d 24:%M", errors='coerce')) + pd.offsets.Day(1)

In [15]: dates2
Out[15]:
0          NaT
1   2015-01-05
2          NaT
3          NaT
4          NaT
5          NaT
6          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now you can fill in the first result with the second:

```
In [16]: dates1.fillna(dates2)
Out[16]:
0   2015-01-04 23:59:00
1   2015-01-05 00:00:00
2   2015-01-05 00:01:00
3   2015-01-05 00:02:00
4   2015-01-05 00:03:00
5   2015-01-05 00:04:00
6   2015-01-05 00:05:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691439/6457938

you can use *strptime*:

```
time = "15:45" # 24h format (military) 
formaT = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, ,'%H:%M').strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

- %H - Hour (24-hour format)
- %M - Minute
- %I - Hour (12-hour format)
- %p - AM or PM