# Convert military time to regular time in python

Tags: python, string, date-formatting

I need to write a Python file that converts military time to regular time. In military time, hours are numbered from 00 to 23, like midnight is 00, 1 a.m. is 01, 1 p.m. is 13. Time in hours and minutes is given as a 4 digit string with minutes following hours and given by 2 digits from 00 to 59. For example, military time 0022 = regular time 12:22 am.

I tried this:

```
time = eval(input('Enter military time: '))

def time():
    return time[:2] + ':' + time[2:]
```

but it does not work with input starts with 0 and I don't know how to convert the input as 'regular time' - 00=12:00

Would like to know what kind of approach should I take.

Comment: Remove `eval` and take a look at the datetime module's [`strftime`/`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [0-23 hour military clock to standard time (hh:mm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691007/0-23-hour-military-clock-to-standard-time-hhmm) (specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691439/2745495))

Comment: your code can't work, too many `time` are defined at the same time (pun intended).